# Gnuplot v2.5 - What is occuring the error?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Recently I started plotting with gnuplot and have a problem plotting multiple curves into one graphical diagram. Since I wrote a .gp script and loaded it, it says

```
multiplot> 'svenBR.dat' using 1:2 w l lw 0.5 lt rgb 'blue', 'johannesBR.dat' using 1:2 w l lw 0.5 lt rgb 'green','sunjayBR.dat' using 1:2 w l
 lw 0.5 lt rgb 'yellow','mariamBR.dat' using 1:2 w l lw 0.5 lt rgb 'red','zhuangBR.dat' using 1:2 w l lw 0.5 lt rgb 'purple','zijuanBR.dat' u
sing 1:2 w l lw 0.5 lt rgb 'orange'
           ^
           "BR.gp" line 10: invalid command
```

My script looks like this:

```
reset

set size 1,1
set multiplot

# First
set size 0.5,0.5
set origin 0,0
plot 'oliverBR.dat' using 1:2 w l lw 0.5 lt rgb 'black',
    'svenBR.dat' using 1:2 w l lw 0.5 lt rgb 'blue', 'johannesBR.dat' using 1:2 w l lw 0.5 lt rgb 'green','sunjayBR.dat' using 1:2 w l lw 0.5 lt rgb 'yellow','mariamBR.dat' using 1:2 w l lw 0.5 lt rgb 'red','zhuangBR.dat' using 1:2 w l lw 0.5 lt rgb 'purple','zijuanBR.dat' using 1:2 w l lw 0.5 lt rgb 'orange'

unset multiplot
```

Do you you know how the problem could be fixed?

Greetings

Comment: It looks like your plot command is split over two lines in your file. Gnuplot treats the line starting with "'svenBR.dat'" as a new command, which it doesn't recognize. Either put it all on a single line, or end the first line of the plot command with a "\" character.

Comment: Also, as shown there is no need to use `multiplot`.  You have only one plot command.